# Laravel Update multiple records with different value

Tags: php, laravel, database, controller, sql-update

I want to update the two records that I got by using the get() with different value.
I fetched the Auth user language with this line of code.

```
$languages = UserLanguage::where('user_ID', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

this is the result of my diedump

[image]

In my view this is the foreach loop

```
<select name="language">
    @foreach( $languages as $language )
        <option value="{{ $language->id }}">{{ $language->language_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

this is the view picture of foreach

[image]

I want to change those 2 records with English and Japanese with 1 button but I don't know how to update those records. please help

Comment: Do you want to translate them in the view or change the database values?

Comment: @IGP I want it to change the database value

Comment: Do you want to update those values in a single select tag or multiple select tags?